# CoffeeScript: Initialize or increment value in array

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

My application has different types of data about a fixed set of countries, kept in arrays of a consistent order.

```
data = 
  oranges: [1,2,3]
  apples: [1,2,3]
  cabbages: [1,2,3]
```

These arrays get combined by various criteria into new arrays, and I find myself wanting to write code like this:

```
fruit = []
for key, arr of data                  # For each array
  if key in ['oranges', 'apples']     # It it meets certain criteria
    for val, i in arr                 # Use the values in the creation of a new array
      fruit[i] += val
```

This doesn't work because if `fruit[i]` is not initialized `+=` won't work.

There are various ways around this.

1) Fill the new `fruit` array with zeros first:

```
for i in [0..len]
  fruit[i] = 0
```

2) Check if `fruit[i]` exists:

```
if fruit[i]?
  fruit[i] += val 
else 
  fruit[i] = val
```

Neither of these seem elegant.  I tried extracting approach 2) into a function but I have to admit that I couldn't quite get my head round it.  I thought about passing in `fruit`, cloning it (with `arr.slice(0)`) and then setting `fruit` to the output, but it didn't feel right to do this on every iteration.

The data format is fixed, but other than that my question is "what is the best way of handling this?"  I'm open to answers that use CoffeeScript and/or ECMAScript 5 and/or JQuery.

Comment: Where is `array` defined?

Comment: @elclanrs sorry.  Fixed typo.  `array` is `arr`

Comment: `fruit[i] = fruit[i] + 1 || 1`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can initialize element of the array with using `||=` or `?=` operator:

```
fruit[i] ||= 0
fruit[i] += val
```

The only difference is that `?=` checks for `null` or `undefined` and `||=` checks for any `false` value.

Comment: `fruit[i] = (fruit[i] or 0) + val` is a one-liner alternative too :)